# Confusion about Couchbase keys and indexes

Tags: couchbase

I have imported a dataset into Couchbase that looks like so:

```
{
  "CLUSTER": "M1M",
  "CLUSTER_NAME": "MARTIN MARIETTA",
  "PRIMARY": "",
  "SET_NUM": "10000163",
  SHORTENED_NAME": "MARTIN MARIETTA MATERIALS",
  "TYPE": "SET",
  "_class": "com.company.aad.xref.model.ClusterCodeXref"
}
```

I had to provide a key-generation strategy, and I made the strategy what I ultimately want my index to look like, `%SET_NUM%::%TYPE%`. So I have a couple of questions:

- Does the key-generation automatically create a field called ID with those 2 elements, or do I need to create an ID column in my CSV dataset?
- How can I create an index out of those 2 fields? I understand how to use the `CREATE INDEX` command with composite fields, but will that index look like the key generated by `%SET_NUM%::%TYPE%`? I need them to be the same, with the `::` in the middle.

I hope my question is clear! Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Couchbase, the ID/key of a document is not actually in the document itself. If you use the `--generate-key` template, your document would look something like:

```
key = "10000163::SET"
{
  "CLUSTER": "M1M",
  "CLUSTER_NAME": "MARTIN MARIETTA",
  "PRIMARY": "",
  "SET_NUM": "10000163",
  SHORTENED_NAME": "MARTIN MARIETTA MATERIALS",
  "TYPE": "SET",
  "_class": "com.company.aad.xref.model.ClusterCodeXref"
}
```

There is no designated "id" field in Couchbase. You can certainly create an id field, but it will be just like any other field.

As for an index, it depends on what kind of query you want to run. You can `CREATE INDEX idx_setnumandtype ON bucketname (SET_NUM, TYPE)` as you mentioned. This is going to be a useful index for queries like: `SELECT b.* FROM bucketname WHERE SET_NUM = 'foo' AND TYPE = 'bar';`

But, if you know those two values and just need to do a lookup of a single document, you don't necessary need to create an index or use N1QL. You can simply do a key/value GET operation. In Java for instance: `bucket.get("10000163::SET")`

Comment: I've accepted your answer, but still have a question - when data is appended to the design document, how will the key be updated?

Comment: Keys are immutable in Couchbase documents. Are you referring to map/reduce indexes? If so, those will be updated (asynchronously) as document changes occur.